# How can I modally present a UIViewController on another Storyboard that's embedded in a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

...and have it embedded in a navigation controller.

I have a storyboard, let's call it MainStoryboard.

On main storyboard (neither is the initialViewController BTW), I have a ViewController, let's call it ViewControllerZ, embedded in a NavigationController, let's call it NavigationControllerZ.

Upon a user clicking a button... I had...

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewControllerZ *vcZ = (ViewControllerZ *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerZ"];
vcZ.delegate = self;
vcZ.blah = blah;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vcZ animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However this doesn't present me with a needed NavigationController. I need the NavigationController from MainStorybard, as the NavBar on ViewControllerZ has a UIBarButtonItem Cancel, to dismiss the modally presented view.

So to get the NavigationController I tried...

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
NavigationViewControllerA *navVcZ = (NavigationViewControllerZ *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationViewControllerZ"];
ViewControllerZ *vcZ  = (ViewControllerZ *)navVcZ.topViewController;
vcZ.delegate = self;
vcZ.blah = blah;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vcZ animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, this does not work and throws a "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller ".

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: where do you do `presentViewController`? can you share that part of the code as well?

Comment: @aytunch I'm presenting it from a view controller on another storyboard. Specifically, it s uibarbuttonitem on the view controllers toolbar. Tap that, and that's the exact code I'm using in my original post.

Comment: I beleive same VC can not be added to two different `UINavigationController` as rootviewcontroller. Read this, it sounds like a similar problem only `UITabBar` being different than `UIStoryBoard`: [Sharing same VC..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710676/sharing-the-same-uiviewcontroller-as-the-rootviewcontroller-with-two-uinavigatio)

Comment: I'm still confused as to how this is presented. Can you show the code that presents the VC? Presumably that's the line that throws? The error indicates you are presenting a VC already in display, not the one just loaded from the storyboard.

Comment: @GrahamPerks I updated my question. `[self.navigationController presentViewController:vcZ animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it seems you add the `navVcZ` as a child view controller like this:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vcZ animated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController addChildViewController:navVcZ];
```

You can directly present the `navVcZ`:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
NavigationViewControllerA *navVcZ = (NavigationViewControllerZ *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationViewControllerZ"];
ViewControllerZ *vcZ  = (ViewControllerZ *)navVcZ.topViewController;
vcZ.delegate = self;
vcZ.blah = blah;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navVcZ animated:YES completion:nil];
```